# Javascript: add an inline style to elements in a page that have a specific computed style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add an inline style to elements in a page that have a specific computed style attribute.

For instance:

```
<head>
    <style>
        p.mim {
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        a.fif {
            cursor:pointer;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <p class="mim">prova</p>
     <a class="fif">prova</a>
</body>
```

I want to add an inline style "cursor:wait" to each element that has "cursor:pointer" set in the computed style:

```
<body>
    <p class="mim" style="cursor:wait;">prova</p>
    <a class="fif" style="cursor:wait;">prova</a>
</body>
```

This is what I tried:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var j = 0; j < elms.length; j++) {

    var crs = getComputedStyle(elm, null).getPropertyCSSValue('cursor') || "";
    crs = crs.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();

    switch (crs) {
        case "pointer":
        case "Pointer":
        case "POINTER":
            elm.style.cursor = "wait";
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there some reason for the `});` at the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is redundant for several reasons, and incomplete for others.

Firstly, `getComptedStyle` doesn't exist in earlier versions of IE. They instead use the `currentStyle` property. Thankfully it is absurdly easy to shim this:

```
if( typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined") getComputedStyle = function(elem) {return elem.currentStyle;};
```

Now that that's been solved, remove that `null` argument as it is completely redundant. Actually, I didn't even know `getComputedStyle` *had* a second argument, but that's just me.

Next, you can get the cursor property just by getting `.cursor` (or `['cursor']`) instead of that `.getPropertyCSSValue` call (which again I have never heard of...). You can also drop the `|| ""` since `getComputedStyle` will return an empty string if the `cursor` property has not been set.

You don't need to trim spaces, but switching to lowercase seems like a good idea just to be on the safe side.

... But then, immediately after `toLowerCase()`, you check THREE different capitalisations of the word? Really?

Additionally, you never define `elm` (which is where your actual problem is), and you should cache the value of `elms.length`.

The final code should look like:

```
if( typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined") getComputedStyle = function(elem) {return elem.currentStyle;};
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), l = elms.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( getComputedStyle(elms[i]).cursor.toLowerCase() === "pointer") {
        elms[i].style.cursor = "wait";
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to undo this, you will need to store an array of elements that you're modifying, loop through it and remove the style (`.style.cursor = "";`).